# Digital Ocean droplet server times out after RoR app installation with Capistrano and NGinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, puma

I setup a RoR application with Nginx+Puma+Capistrano by following this DigitalOcean guide :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

I was able to setup everything and got Capistrano deployments working, but when I access my droplet with it's IP, it keeps loading the page and nothing shows up.
The connection basically times out.

Neither the nginx logs, nor the Puma logs (access+error) show anything.
both Puma and nginx are running, though.

Ping shows that the server IP is reachable, so I think it has got to do with the webserver running on this droplet

What could be the cause, and how to debug it?

Here's the `nginx` configuration:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:/home/deployer/apps/<my-app>/shared/tmp/sockets/<my-app>-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deployer/apps/<my-app>/current/public;
  access_log /home/deployer/apps/<my-app>/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deployer/apps/<my-app>/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

And here is the `deploy.rb` file:

```
# Change these
server 'XX.XXX.XX.XX', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:<my-repo>/<my-app>.git'
set :application,     '<my-app>'
set :user,            'deployer'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
# set :ssh_options,     {:forward_agent => true}
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :rvm_type, :system

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
# after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Comment: Do you get a 404 page when you visit  

`
http://domainname.com/404.html
http://ipaddress_of_droplet/404.html
`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @robzolkos, but I don't see a 404.html, it has the same result - request timing out

Comment: @AmanAlam did you solve this problem?

Comment: @LyzardKyng No, unfortunately, I ended up creating a new droplet with RoR env prebuilt in it. That helped though